# Assembly 32-bit - Calling a program from another program

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm currently learning Assembly, I'm not very new but maybe since 1 - 2 months back. I am using 32-bit Assembly, NASM to assemble it into a .o file  and MinGW/gcc to compile to a .exe file. but It takes so much time to type "nasm -f elf " in the nasm directory and then do "gcc  -o " all the time. so I wanted to create a quick program where I just start it. and all that gets executed.

So I want the program to 1st start the nasm assembler. then wait till it's done (like when you call another function), and after that, I want to start the gcc compiler, and wait till that is done. I know it's quite easy to make in batch files, but I still want to learn how to do it in assembly, incase I need to do it someday. So the question is, how do I start a program (with start/console parameters), and then also wait for it to exit.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the Win32 API, start the executable with [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) and wait for it to finish with [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or if you're linking against `libc`/`msvcrt` you could probably use the `system()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a program with [`CreateProcessA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) and wait for its end with [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx). The GCC-linker (LD) needs also a suffix with the number of the pushed bytes (e.g. "@4", one dword = four bytes). That is one reason to use another linker.

Here's a simple example to start a shell (cmd.exe) with a "dir"-command:

**exec_dir.asm:**

```
STRUC _STARTUPINFO                      ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx
    .cb:                resd 1
    .lpReserved:        resd 1
    .lpDesktop:         resd 1
    .lpTitle:           resd 1
    .dwX:               resd 1
    .dwY:               resd 1
    .dwXSize:           resd 1
    .dwYSize:           resd 1
    .dwXCountChars:     resd 1
    .dwYCountChars:     resd 1
    .dwFillAttribute:   resd 1
    .dwFlags:           resd 1
    .wShowWindow:       resw 1
    .cbReserved2:       resw 1
    .lpReserved2:       resd 1
    .hStdInput:         resd 1
    .hStdOutput:        resd 1
    .hStdError:         resd 1
ENDSTRUC

STRUC _PROCESS_INFORMATION              ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684873.aspx
    .hProcess:      resd 1
    .hThread:       resd 1
    .dwProcessId:   resd 1
    .dwThreadId:    resd 1
ENDSTRUC

section .data
    startupinfo:
        istruc _STARTUPINFO
        iend
    procinfo:
        istruc _PROCESS_INFORMATION
        iend
    app_fullpath: db "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",0
    params: db "/c dir", 0
    msg: db `\n\nok.\n`,0

global _main
EXTERN _ExitProcess@4, _CreateProcessA@40,_WaitForSingleObject@8
EXTERN _puts, _fflush

section .text
_main:

    ; CreateProcess(app_fullpath,params,0,0,false,0,0,0,&startupinfo,&procinfo)
    push procinfo
    push startupinfo
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push params
    push app_fullpath
    call _CreateProcessA@40         ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx

    ; WaitForSingleObject( procinfo.hProcess, INFINITE );
    push -1         ; INFINITE
    push dword [procinfo + _PROCESS_INFORMATION.hProcess]
    call _WaitForSingleObject@8

    ; puts ("ok."), fflush to flush the stdout-buffer
    push msg
    call _puts
    mov dword [esp], 0
    call _fflush
    add esp, 4

    ; return 0
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

In a (Windows) Command Prompt:

```
PATH C:\MinGW\bin;<Path\to\nasm.exe>
nasm.exe -fwin32 exec_dir.asm
gcc.exe -m32 -o exec_dir.exe exec_dir.obj
exec_dir.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would suggest several easy ways:

1. Switch to [FASM](http://flatassembler.net) or what is the same, but with more advanced IDE: [Fresh](http://fresh.flatassembler.net) - they will compile and run in a single key press (or mouse click). FASM IDE is only for Windows, Fresh IDE will work fine in Linux and Windows. Notice, that the syntax of FASM is very close to NASM syntax, so you will not have big problems to move.
2. Use some IDE for NASM that will make everything in a similar way.
3. Make small .BAT file that to run the commands in automatic way. This is the simplest way to make exactly what you ask in your question.

Well, my suggestion is somehow different from your question, but IMO, using good IDE is essential for productive work, regardless of the language you use.

Answer (score 0):

if your utilisng windows, you can utilise a bat command to do this, an example would be:
nasm BOOTLOADER.asm -f bin -o BOOTLOADER.bin
pause
yet thats to convert a file named BOOTLOADER.asm into a binary file, its the same syntax as in the nasm manual, becuase the bat command sends to comd, and cmd utilises the environment variables, so when you install nasm you install this and so can just click to run this bat file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).